# Is there a way of rendering LaTeX equations in Crystal Reports?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, crystal-reports, latex

I'm developing a report in Crystal Reports and need to render some math formulas and equations in it. The formulas and equations are stored in a SQL Server database in plain text (using LaTeX markup).

Getting them to render in HTML is not a problem, because I'm using MathJax to do the work at browser level (in either HTML/CSS or MathML).

The real problem is: how can I get these equations rendered in the report? I've searched throught the web and found nothing about it. Doing some more search at the Crystal interface, the only thing I've found is inserting the (obsolete) "Microsoft Equation Editor" as a OLE object in the report, but neither this worked.

So, how render these LaTeX math equations in this Crystal report? Is there some (obscure) component/plugin that does the job? If not, is there a better manner of doing this? Someone already got and resolved a similar use-case?

OBS 1: I must have this report generated in PDF because of already validated standards in use at my job.

OBS 2: The app which will generate this report is a ASP.NET MVC 3 web app, with a SQL Server 2008 database (using NHibernate).

Comment: I don't know crystal well enough, but you may need to hit a web service that has latex installed and get either a rendered PDF | PostScript | PNG (whatever) to include in said report.

Comment: Similarly, i'm not very familiar with LaTeX but you set text fields in Crystal to be interpreted as HTML (all be it with limited functionality)- this may help

Comment: These equations, are they static or dynamic? That is, are you expecting them to change by virtue of the data?

Comment: @Orbling These equations are dynamic. They are filled by the user and saved in the database and may change in the future.

Comment: @LeeTickett The problem is not only showing in HTML, because I need to "compile" the LaTeX markup to some image or typesetting that renders the equation like it was handwritten. Mainly because it could be equations or even chemistry formulas.

Comment: @RenanMarks: In which case, I think you need to do it either the way Xepoch suggests above, via a web service that you make - or as craig suggests in the answer below, if you can be doing with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found** a workaround that is at the same time elegant and not relies on extending the Crystal Reports using C.

I've found this small and simple "latex equation renderer": [mimeTeX](http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html). Using it, I'm able to **render latex equations into GIF images** (as a CGI application). With that, I created a **phantom byte array field** in the datatable where the report is getting data.

Here is what I've done:

1. Recover the latex equation markup from my real database;
2. Query mimeTeX using this markup and mimeTeX returns a gif image;
3. Take this image and convert it to png format (Crystal surprisingly do not support GIF files);
4. Finally put this PNG image (its bytes) in the phantom field created in the datatable used by the report;
5. Now you can use this field in the report! The images for each record (equation) are generated and displayed without problems!

<strike>The **only drawback** I've found until now using this approach is that *all the images are streched to the same size of the field placeholder*. If the images have sizes that varies much, some will be displayed pixelated and others will become "squashed". But I'm looking forward how to resolve this issue!</strike>

--- Edit ---

Solved the "squashed images" problem. I resize the images in code maintaining their aspect ratio and "pasting" them in a fixed size image. Now all the images get the same size and doesn't get squashed!

Here is the code for the resizing:

```
MemoryStream ResizeImage(Stream OriginalFile, int NewWidth, int MaxHeight, bool OnlyResizeIfWider)
{
    int finalWidth = NewWidth;
    int finalHeight = MaxHeight;

    System.Drawing.Image FullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(OriginalFile);

    // Prevent using images internal thumbnail
    FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
    FullsizeImage.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

    if (OnlyResizeIfWider)
    {
        if (FullsizeImage.Width <= NewWidth)
        {
            NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width;
        }
    }

    int NewHeight = FullsizeImage.Height * NewWidth / FullsizeImage.Width;
    if (NewHeight > MaxHeight)
    {
        // Resize with height instead
        NewWidth = FullsizeImage.Width * MaxHeight / FullsizeImage.Height;
        NewHeight = MaxHeight;
    }

    System.Drawing.Image NewImage = FullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);

    // Clear handle to original file so that we can overwrite it if necessary
    FullsizeImage.Dispose();

    MemoryStream bmpStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Put in a new image of A x B pixels to evict distortion
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(finalWidth, finalHeight))
    {
        using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            canvas.Clear(Color.White);
            canvas.DrawImage(NewImage, 0, 0);
            canvas.Save();
        }

        bitmap.Save(bmpStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }

    return bmpStream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a [user-function library (UFL)](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/Creating_UFL_C.html#601884) to do this.  Pass the LaTeX representation of the formula to the UFL, generate an image representation of the formula, return the image's URL.

To use the path, insert a 'picture', then reference the UFL's function in the 'graphic location' property:

```
//Insert | Picture...; graphic location conditional formula
latex({table.latex_field})
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the best one (by using an API, etc) but seems like a bit "excessive" in the point that the project is being developed entirely in C#. Falling back to pure C is a little "out of scope" for a solution like this. However is nice to know that Crystal Reports have extension points!

Comment: If it helps, you can also build UFLs in Delphi, COM, and Java.