# Load Image from file in Crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Hi I'm working with crystal reports in a asp.net application with c#, my problem is
that the generated report should have a QR code that is generated with the following code

```
            QRCode qrcode = new QRCode();
            qrcode.Data = "Id Asociacion Civil:" + query.fiIdAsocCivil + "\n" + "Fecha de Registro:" + query.fdFechaReg.ToShortDateString() + "\n" + "Nombre de la Asociación:" + query.fcRazonSocial;
            qrcode.X = 12;

            // Create QR-Code and encode barcode to Jpeg format
            qrcode.ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            if (Request.ApplicationPath == "/")
            {
                qrcode.drawBarcode(@"\\cjfapppba\ssac\Ejemplo1.jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                qrcode.drawBarcode((MapPath(@"~/Ejemplo1.jpg")));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {

            Label1.Text = x.Message;
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Every time I hit the button "report"  to create a report the code to generate the code is executed and overwrites the last qrcode. My problem is that if I scan the qr code it ios updated correctly but in my report it doesn't. I tried adding a OLE object as other forums suggest but no success yet.
Any advice on how to achieve this?

I call the report with this code

```
  GeneraCodigo();

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {

            case "Registro":



                    var strRep = new StringBuilder();
                    strRep.Append("<script languaje=javascript>window.open('http://portalrpt/reportes/default.aspx?rep=SSAC/Constancia.rpt&mod=136&sf={AsocCivil.fiIdAsocCivil}=");

                    strRep.Append(idAC);



                    strRep.Append("','','width=670,height=570,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes');</script>");

                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "WOpen", strRep.ToString());
```

And method GeneraCodigo() is for generate the new qr code

Answer (score 0):

You may want to adjust the approach that I suggested for [rendering LaTex equations in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518829/is-there-a-way-of-rendering-latex-equations-in-crystal-reports).